# Big Oh notation - push and pop

Tags: big-o

I think I am starting to understand at least the theory behind big Oh notation, i.e. it is a way of measuring the rate at which the speed of a function grows.  In other words, big O quantifies an algorithm's efficiency.  But the implementation of it is something else.

For example, in the best case scenario push and pull operations will be O(1) because the number of steps it takes to remove from or add to the stack are going to be fixed.  Regardless of the value, the process will be the same.

I'm trying to envision how a sequence of events such as push and pop can degrade performance from O(1) to O(n^2).  If I have an array of n/2 capacity, n push and pop operations, and a dynamic array that doubles or halves its capacity when full or half full, how is it possible that the sequence in which these operations occur can affect the speed in which a program completes?  Since push and pop work on the top element of the stack, I'm having trouble seeing how efficiency goes from a constant to O(n^2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You're assuming that the dynamic array does its resize operations quite intelligently. If this is not the case, however, you might end up with O(n^2) runtime: Suppose the array does not double its size when full but simply is resized to size+1. Also, suppose it starts with size 1. You'd insert the first element in O(1). When inserting the second elment, the array would need to be resized to size 2, requiring it to copy the previous value. When inserting element k, it would currently have size k-1, and need to be resized to size k, resulting in k-1 elements that need to be copied, and so on.

Thus, for inserting n elements, you'd end up with copying the array n-1 times: O(n) resizes. The copy operations are also linearly dependent on n since the more elements are have been inserted, the more need to be copied: O(n) copies per resize. This results in O(n*n) = O(n^2) as its runtime complexity.

Answer (score 2):

If I implement a stack as (say) a linked list, then pushes and pops will always be constant time (i.e. O(1)).

I would not choose a dynamic array implementation for a stack, unless runtime wasn't an issue for me, I happened to have a dynamic array ready-built and available to use, and I didn't have a more efficient stack implementation handy. However, if I did use an array that resized up or down when it became full or half-empty respectively, its runtime would be O(1) while the numbers of pushes and pops are low enough not to trigger the resize and O(n) when there is a resize (hence overall O(n)).

I can't think of a case where a dynamic array used as a stack could deliver performance as bad as O(n^2) unless there was a bug in its implementation.

Comment: ... and the sort of bug that it would take is well-described by @rainer. A subtlety here is that when I said "pushes and pops will always be constant time" for a linked list, an individual push or pop will be constant time, but `n` pushes or pops will, of course, take time proportional to `n`, as pointed out by @rainer.